# How to enter overlined characters?

Tags: text-editing, unicode

Example: R̅E̅S̅

What I already tried, to no avail: Type `R`, followed by `C-x 8 RET OVERLINE RET`

What works but is not nice: Copy the example above and edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [combining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) overline (U+0305), not a “normal” overline U+8254. `C-x 8 RET comb TAB over TAB`.